# every star compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is known that every compact space is star compact ( some of authors called it star finite).

I cannot find an example for a star compact subset $\mathbb{R}$ which is not compact. Is it true that star compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$  is compact?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131665/a-star-compact-subset-of-mathbbr-is-closed Are you friends?

Comment: I'm not sure most authors equate *star compact* and *star finite*; see the discussion under [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95543/is-there-a-topological-space-which-is-star-compact-but-not-star-countable) and consider adding an explicit definition.

Comment: A space $X$ is star compact if for any open cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $X$, there is a finite $F\subseteq  X$ such that $X= st(A,\mathcal{V}) = \cup\{ V \in \mathcal{V}: V \cap F \neq \emptyset$

Comment: So you have no problem with my putting this in your Question, to make it self-contained?  I would say this defines *star finite*.  Note the definition given in the earlier Question for *star compact*.  Of course $\mathbb{R}$ is a $T_4$ space, so there the notions are equivalent.